# Java - Error with a While loop not exiting when if condition hits break:

Tags: java, class, if-statement, netbeans, while-loop

I am a beginner programmer so bear with me. I am currently working on a project for my coding class, where I am tasked with writing a program to simulate a batter facing a pitcher in a baseball game for one turn at bat. I think the problem in my code is a logic error, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I have tried added additional while loops and if statements but nothing has worked. The code in my batter class and pitcher class work completely fine, it's just the code in my driver. Stuff sometimes breaks out of loop when it's suppose to and other times it doesn't and sometimes it repeats the same line of text when it's not suppose to. 
I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank you so much in advance.

Here is my code for the driver program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Batter batter = new Batter();
  batter.getname();
  // making the pitcher object and calling the get name method.
  Pitcher pitcher = new Pitcher();
  pitcher.getname();
  System.out.println(pitcher.getname() + " is pitching to " + batter.getname());

  while (true) {
    int ball = 0;
    int strike = 0;
    // desiding if the hit method gets called on the batter object
    if (pitcher.pitch() == false) {
      ball++;
      System.out.println("The count is " + ball + " balls " + strike + " strikes");
    }
    if (pitcher.pitch()== false && ball ==4 ){
      System.out.println("The count is " + ball + " balls " + strike + " strikes");
      System.out.println(batter.getname() + " walked.");
      break;
    }

    if (batter.hit() == false) {
      strike++;
      System.out.println("The count is " + ball + " balls " + strike + " strikes");
    }
    if (batter.hit() == false && strike == 3){
      System.out.println("The count is " + ball + " balls " + strike + " strikes");
      System.out.println(batter.getname() + " struck out.");
      break;
    }

    if (batter.hit() == true && pitcher.pitch() == true) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Think of method calls as verbs. Every time you `hit()` or `pitch()` is a unique action. But you are calling those methods as if they were idempotent (a fancy word for *no side effects*). Save the result(s) in *local variables* and your problems should be resolved. However, I also have to say using `==` for testing `boolean` types is a code wart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance I'd recommend the following.

For a start change to this as there is no point calling the getter every time so give it a variable name:

```
Batter batter = new Batter();
bName = batter.getname();

Pitcher pitcher = new Pitcher();
pName = pitcher.getname();

You can then replace batter.getName() & pitcher.Name() with bName & pName
```

I'm not a fan of while(true) and you need move ball and strike so try this instead:

```
int ball = 0, strike = 0;
boolean game = true;
while(game){
```

Then i'm not sure if your second if is right as you check for pitcher.pitch()==false in first if so try second one as:

```
if(ball == 4) {
```

Finally replace break with:

```
game = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the values back to 0 every time the loop starts. Because you include the assignment *inside* the loop, it returns every time. Please note the number of the comments, meant to be read chronologically.

```
 while (true) {
    int ball = 0;
    // [3] here, we are resetting ball to 0, so the ++ below is negated
    int strike = 0;
    if (pitcher.pitch() == false) {
        ball++;
        // [1] lets assume we get here, the value of ball now is 1.
        // [2] we go to comment [3]
```

if you want to maintain the result, you should set the values before the loop.

```
 int ball = 0;
 int strike = 0;
 // [1] both are 0 now
 while (true) {
    // [3] now, we maintain ball is 1. see 4

    if (pitcher.pitch() == false) {
        ball++;
        // [2] setting ball to 1, repeating loop, see [3]
        // [4] now we increment ball again, ball has value 2. Etc.
```

Comment: And of course, the alterartions suggested by @Super Hans are an improvement, but the main problem with this code is the assignment inside the loop.